# What tool (library) can now be used to display 3D models in an application written in React Native?

Tags: react-native, three.js, 3d, expo, react-three-drei

What tool (library) can now be used to display 3D models (and interact with them - twist, zoom) in an application written in react native? I tried a bunch of expo-three, three, expo-gl, but they don't even run examples from the official repository in expo go. Help please, deadlines are burning

I tried expo-three, but it doesn’t want to start at all, then the packages are not the same, then it says that it won’t work natively, only in the browser. I tried it a year ago - at least the examples were launched, now nothing will start at all, not with me, not from the examples

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@viro-community/react-viro

Unfortunately not designed to run within Expo Ecosystem.

Another possible alternative is using ThreeJS inside WebView